# SelectableList does not display Selected item when selection change

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have an issue with a SelectableList. When i display the list for the first time, the default defined item is selected in the list. But when i click on a different item of the list, the item does not appears as selected in the list, and the index is `undefined`. any suggestions ?

This is the sample code of my `SelectableList` :

```js
import React from 'react';
import {List, ListItem, MakeSelectable} from 'material-ui/List';
import Avatar from 'material-ui/Avatar';

const SelectableList = MakeSelectable(List);

class ListExampleSelectable extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
      super();
    }

    componentWillMount() {
      this.setState({
        selectedIndex: this.props.defaultValue,
      });
    }

    handleRequestChange(event, index) {
      this.setState({
        selectedIndex: index,
      });
      console.log(index);
    };

    render() {
        return ( 
           <SelectableList value = {this.state.selectedIndex}
            onClick = {this.handleRequestChange.bind(this)} >
            
                <ListItem value="1" primaryText="Menu1" leftAvatar={<Avatar src="img1.png" />}/>
                <ListItem value="2" primaryText="Menu2" leftAvatar={<Avatar src="img2.png" />}/>
                <ListItem value="3" primaryText="Menu3" leftAvatar={<Avatar src="img3.png" />}/>
            </SelectableList>
        );
    }
}

export default ListExampleSelectable;
```

and i use my component like this:

```
import MyList from './ExampleSelectable.jsx';
```

and inside a drawer i have :

```
<MyList defaultValue="1"/>
```

The list is displayed with the first item selected, but when i click on a different item, the selection does not move on the clicked item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, things are working great. keep in mind these few things if you have this issue:

1- Like @erik-sn said, material-ui uses `onChange` instead of `onClick` as the event handler

2- I wasn't including the `react-tap-event-plugin` that's why the click events not registered and handled. So install the `react-tap-event-plugin`. Material-ui Components use react-tap-event-plugin to listen for touch / tap / clickevents. More info on the [Material-ui getting started page](http://www.material-ui.com/#/get-started/installation). More infos about `react-tap-event-plugin` [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tap-event-plugin).

**Usage** after installation :

`var injectTapEventPlugin = require("react-tap-event-plugin");`
`injectTapEventPlugin();`

3- To avoid the undefined value when using (or printing) the index value of the clicked List Item, dont forget to bind to the component in order to have access in the callback (more detail on this post : [React this.setState is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31045716/react-this-setstate-is-not-a-function)

This is the final code of my SelectableList component (ps: dont mind the class name and method....)

```js
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';
import Avatar from 'material-ui/Avatar';
import {List, ListItem, MakeSelectable} from 'material-ui/List';

let SelectableList = MakeSelectable(List);

export default class DashboardPage extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {selectedIndex: 1};
        }

    handleRequestChange (event, index) {
        this.setState({
            selectedIndex: index
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (<div>{this.renderAside()}</div>);
    }

    renderAside() {
        return (
            <SelectableList value={this.state.selectedIndex} onChange={this.handleRequestChange.bind(this)}>
                <ListItem value={1} primaryText="Menu1" leftAvatar={<Avatar src="img1.png" />}/>
                <ListItem value={2} primaryText="Menu2" leftAvatar={<Avatar src="img2.png" />}/>
                <ListItem value={3} primaryText="Menu3" leftAvatar={<Avatar src="img3.png" />}/>
                <ListItem value={4} primaryText="Menu3" leftAvatar={<Avatar src="img4.png" />}/>
            </SelectableList>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: makeSelectable is not currently part of the v1 roadmap, see: https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/issues/7270

Answer (score 0):

I believe that material-ui uses `onChange` instead of `onClick` as the event handler:

```
   render() {
      return (
        <ComposedComponent
          value={this.state.selectedIndex}
          onChange={this.handleRequestChange}
        >
          {this.props.children}
        </ComposedComponent>
      );
    }
```

So when you click it is calling your function - But passing no parameters to it. Try changing it to `onChange`.

Comment: Nothing happens when i use the `onclick` event, seems like the `handleRequestChange` function is not even called...